# Debug not working for Win CE 5.0 Device

Tags: c#, debugging, smart-device

I'm working with a handheld device running Windows CE 5.0.  The program runs, however I'm not able to debug and hopefully its something simple and stupid burried in project settings somewhere.

So, as to not mess up the main app, I decide I'll start a brand new SmartDevice application.  So MS builds its default settings, environment, path for the new project and defaults it's first form "Form1".  I shrink the form up some and put a single button on it with code in its CLICK event for "This.Close();"

Compile and try to debug and it comes up with the empty circle with warning triangle icon...

"The breakpoint will not currently be hit.  The specified module hasnot been loaded."

What's up...

---

To answer Bryan's question... I'm connected via USB via ActiveSynch 4.5 the other programmer in our office uses the same configuration for debugging but he's out of town this week and I've been tasked with some review of processes.

Also, I'm using Visual Studio 2005, not 2010...

Comment: How do you have the device connected to your development PC? How are you deploying to the device?

Comment: No one is using VS 2010 for this stuff :( Can't open the projects.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never tried to connect to a device in that manner.  My experience has been with running over the network.  There were some security things we had to do.  Like run conmanclient2, for example.  I don't know if that is needed with USB.  Sorry I can't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the version of Compact-Framework SDK.  I had to uninstall, re-install and put CF SDK SP1 in... Debug now working...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible your device may be "locked down" by the device manufacturer or the mobile operator making it difficult to debug a running application on the device.
MSDN has a great resource center on debugging Windows Mobile applications at:

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158521.aspx

In the middle of the page you will find a note about default security settings and a link to an article titled "Deployment, Setup, Security and You".

You may want to sign your application before having Visual Studio deploy to it to your device.  You can find more information about that at:

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms839681.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your option, however as noted in my own finding (FINALLY), it was from a corrupt compact framework SDK.  After re-installing with SP1, all worked well... nothing about security or certs.